# Comparing two models in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

Lets imaging the we have model:

```
public class InheritModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string OtherData { get; set; }
}
```

We have a controller with View, that represents this model:

```
private InheritModel GetAll()
{
    return new InheritModel
    {
        Name = "name1",
        Description = "decs 1",
        OtherData = "other"
    };
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(GetAll());
}
```

Now we can edit this in View, change some data and post in back to server:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(InheritModel model)
{
    var merged = new MergeModel();
    return View(merged.Merge(model, GetAll()));
}
```

What i need to do:

- In view we have a reproduction of model
- User change something and post
- Merge method need to compare field-by-field posted model and previous model
- Merge method create a new InheritModel with data that was changed in posted model, all other data should be null

Can somebody help me to make this Merge method?

**UPDATE(!)**

It's not a trivial task. Approaching like:

```
public InheritModel Merge(InheritModel current, InheritModel orig)
{
    var result = new InheritModel();
    if (current.Id != orig.Id) 
    {
        result.Id = current.Id;
    }
}
```

Not applicable. It's should be Generic solution. We have more than 200 properties in the model. And the first model is built from severeal tables from DB.

Comment: Couldn't you just use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public InheritModel Merge(InheritModel current, InheritModel orig)
{
    var result = new InheritModel();
    if (current.Id != orig.Id) 
    {
        result.Id = current.Id;
    }
    if (current.Name != orig.Name) 
    {
        result.Name = current.Name;
    }
    ... for the other properties

    return result;
}
```

Another possibility is to use reflection and loop through all properties and set their values:

```
public InheritModel Merge(InheritModel current, InheritModel orig)
{
    var result = new InheritModel();
    var properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(InheritModel));
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in properties)
    {
        var currentValue = property.GetValue(current);
        if (currentValue != property.GetValue(orig))
        {
            property.SetValue(result, currentValue);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Obviously this works only for 1 level nesting of properties.

Comment: If you can write example using reflation it will be fantastic. :) i spent 3 hours yesterday to make a right working method but with out any results.

Comment: @EvgeniyLabunskiy, example provided. Also if you have 200 properties in your view model you should probably consider changing your design.

Comment: Thanks, but it's compare model to model, to field to field. And in result i have current model posted to server. Any ideas?

Comment: @EvgeniyLabunskiy, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: about "consider changing your design". It's edit page of big part of system settings and we cannot change this cause this page is from requirements from customer

Comment: "I don't understand what you mean". I need to loop over all fields in the model and compare then one by one. that create the new model of same type where put only changed fields from the loop (all other fields should be null). In your example you compare current and origin model, not their fields.

Comment: @EvgeniyLabunskiy, I am comparing properties, not fields. You have fields in your classes? Normally fields should be private. The default model binder never works with fields. It can assign only properties. So you should have private fields which are encapsulated into public properties.

Comment: sorry, i mean properties. Exectly the Values of Properties

Comment: Problem was that comparing should be: !currentValue.Equals(editedValue). Fixed and it's work :) thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Per topic, it seems that what you want is a sort of "change tracking" mechanism which is definitely not trivial or simple by any means. Probably, it makes sense to use any modern ORM solution to do that for you, does it?

Because otherwise you need to develop something that maintains the "context" (the 1st level object cache) like EF's `ObjectContext` or NH's `Session` that would be generic solution.

Also, there is no information on what happens at the lower level - how do you actualy save the data. Do you already have some mechanism that saves the object by traversing it's "non-null" properties?

Comment: Yes, exactly! :) we need to track changes, but in more simple way - just create model with changed data and nulls for unchanged data.

Comment: @EvgeniyLabunskiy, but if you want the generic solution then you should anyway have this mechanism somewhere - at either "high"/app level or in your data-access layer saving mechanism. I'd suggest the latter since it is going to be more generic. And - yes - it is complicated. Simplest possible thing - is to use reflection over all public properties or properties marked with some special attribute. Otherwise, you just have to make those property-by-property comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar project experience, which made me thought a lot about the original design. Think the following question:

> You have a view that representing a model, then users modified
>   something of the model in the view, all the **CHANGES** are posted to
>   server and the model is modified, and then it's saved to database
>   probably. What's posted to the server on earth?

An instance of `InheritModel`? No. You want the changes only. It's actually part of `InheritModel`, it's a `InheritModel Updater`, it's an instance of `Updater<InheritModel>`. And in your question you need to merge two models, because your `Update` method looks like:

```
public InheritModel Update(InheritedModel newModel)
{
    //assign the properties of the newModel to the old, and save it to db
    //return the latest version of the InheritedModel
}
```

Now ask yourself: why do I need a whole instance of `InheritedModel` when I just want to update one property only?

So my final solution is: posting the changes to the controller, the argument is something like a `Updater<TModel>`, not `TModel` itself. And the `Updater<TModel>` can be *applied* to a `TModel`, the properties metioned in the updater is assigned and saved. There shouldn't a MERGE operation.

Comment: The main problem is that i require really the all InheritModel. Even with null properties (we have a tree organization of data, so if this property is null, system get it from upper record in tree)

Comment: @EvgeniyLabunskiy: Since it's a EDIT page, why do you need those properties users can't edit? If a property `IdentityCode` is readonly, what's the difference if the field is posted or not?